# IllegalStateException target must not be null

Tags: android, android-widget

hi i want to create an activity in which i want to change the content of list accorfing to the location selected so i wrote an overlay class

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
        {
            @Override
            public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) 
            {
                super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

                //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
             return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
            {   
                //---when user lifts his finger---
                if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
                    GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                        (int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY());

                           double x = p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 ;
                           double y= p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ; 
                           String url="http://api.v3.factual.com/t/global?geo={\"$circle\":{\"$center\":["+x+","+y+"],\"$meters\":5000}}&KEY=uZSowx1CRS4oD2R8kQGGgjkbFoDMHlriDl1IAoQc";
                      url=URLEncoder.encode(url);
                           HttpGet get=new HttpGet(url);
                          try {
                            HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);
                        Log.i("hello",EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }                            
                return true;
            }        
        }
```

but when i click on any item it shows me force close and shows the error
Java.lang.IllegalStateException target Host must not be null and set in parameters please help how to solve this bug.
and here is the log cat of error

```
03-30 12:30:52.267: E/AndroidRuntime(692): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at factual.box.android.Factual_Mapping$MapOverlay.onTouchEvent(Factual_Mapping.java:91)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTouchEvent(OverlayBundle.java:63)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:625)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-30 12:30:52.277: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 12:30:52.297: I/dalvikvm(692): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-30 12:30:52.317: I/dalvikvm(692): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: can you please post whole error log so that I can understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not encode, use below code.

```
         String url = "http://api.v3.factual.com/t/global?KEY=uZSowx1CRS4oD2R8kQGGgjkbFoDMHlriDl1IAoQc";
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter("geo", "{\"$circle\":{\"$center\":[\" + x + \",\" + y + \"],\"$meters\":5000}}");
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You encoded "http://" so your url doesnt valid
Try to use something like this

```
String geoData=URLEncoder.encode("{\"$circle\":{\"$center\":["+x+","+y+"],\"$meters\":5000}}");  
String key = "uZSowx1CRS4oD2R8kQGGgjkbFoDMHlriDl1IAoQc";  
String urlPattern  ="http://api.v3.factual.com/t/global?geo=%s&KEY=%s";  
String url = String.format(urlPattern, geoData,key);
```

Comment: please give some java code of lines how to encode this url so that i will get my json data. url  showing correct json data on my browser.